# Passing ViewModel to Web-Api action

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to pass an ViewModel object to WebApi controller action instead of separate params?

Instead of using:

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(string p1, string p2)
    {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

I would like to use:

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(TestVM testVM)
    {
        // some logic
    }
}

public class TestVM
{
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work for me. When I call /api/contacts/?P1=aaa&P2=bbb the testVM object doesn't get populated (null).

Also, I would like the TestVM to have valdiation attribtues defined and use ModelState.IsValid in my API controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless told otherwise WebApi will deserialise complex models using the content/body of the request. To tell WebApi to use the Url to construct the model you need to specify the [FromUri] attribute:

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts([FromUri]TestVM testVM)
{
    // some logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kind of late to post another answer but I thought it could be useful for anyone who uses .net core as a web API service

```
public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts([FromQuery]TestVM testVM)
```